# Is it possible (and how) to load SVG string in Phaser 3 instead of loading it from path/url?

Tags: javascript, svg, phaser-framework

I have several SVGs in my code which I would like to use with Phaser (specifically for particles) without saving them into separate SVG files.

```
const svgString = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 10h-10v-10h-4v10h-10v4h10v10h4v-10h10z"/></svg>`;

function preload()
{
    // Usual way
    this.load.svg('plus', 'assets/svg/plus.svg');

    // What I would like to do
    this.load.svg('plus', svgString)
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this (and how)?

Comment: will you be able to use this library? 
https://github.com/Rich-Harris/svg-parser

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: Neither resolves my question as I'm talking about specific use case for Phaser 3 framework - https://phaser.io/phaser3 but thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question was answered on Phaser 3 forum - https://phaser.discourse.group/t/is-it-possible-and-how-to-load-svg-string-in-phaser-3-instead-of-loading-it-from-path-url/9668

```
const svgString = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M24 10h-10v-10h-4v10h-10v4h10v10h4v-10h10z"/></svg>`;

function preload()
{
    const blob = new Blob([svgString], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    this.load.svg('plus', url)
}
```